# Doubly linked list class

Tags: c++, doubly-linked-list

I am trying to make a double linked list. Function push(int x) should add a node to the list and make the correct link. I use:

```
class Node {
public:
    int value;
    Node* next;
    Node* prev;

public:
    Node() {}
    void set_value(int x) { value = x; }
    void set_next(Node* x) { next = x; }
    void set_prev(Node* x) { prev = x; }

    Node* get_next() { return next; }
    Node* get_prev() { return prev; }        
};

class deque {
    public:
        Node* head;
        Node* tail;
    public:
        deque() { head = NULL; tail = NULL; }
        void push(int x) {
             Node* n = new Node();
             n->set_value(x);
             n->set_next(NULL);
             n->set_prev(NULL);

             Node* t = head; //link to the next node           
             if (t == NULL) {
                 head = n; 
             } else {
                 while (t->get_next() != NULL) {
                       t = t->get_next();
                 }
                 t->set_next(n);
             }
        }     
};
```

As I have tested the part that connects a node to the next one works fine but I am having some troubles connecting the node to the previous one. One that comes in mind is a variation of the first one:

```
Node* t = tail;             
if (t == NULL) {
    tail = n; 
} else {
    while (t->get_prev() != NULL) {
          t = t->get_prev();
    }
    t->set_prev(n);
}
```

But by using this, the tail node is always the current n node if only the node n is the one and only node in the queue... What should I do? thanks a lot

Comment: Why not simply using something like `n->set_prev(tail); tail->set_next(n); tail = n;` with proper NULL-pointer verification?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Drawing always helps with such data structures. What you have currently:

[image]

You correctly set `t`'s `next` with: `t->set_next(n);`. What is missing is the arrow underneath it, and it's: `n->set_prev(t)`.

In general, when dealing with doubly-linked lists, a call to `set_next` should always (most of the time) be accompanied by a call to `set_prev` on `set_next`'s argument. It's because of the doubly-linked list's property:

`x->next == y` *implies* `y->prev == x`, and `y->prev == x` *implies* `x->next == y`.